# Is there a way to set a value from first launch and use it if the app is already launched?

Tags: ios, swift

I take a permission from the user only in the first launch and if s/he approve I want to do some functions. I but a boolean variable if s/he click ok the variable will be true and do the functions but my problem is when it's the second launch of the app I don't know if user was approve or not.

Here I check if its the first Launch

```
if (isFirstLaunch()){
    self.AlertOnce(Message: " hello may i use ....")
}
```

This is the code of the alert message:

```
func AlertOnce (Message: String){
    let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "أهلا بك", message: Message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

    alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "موافق", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { ACTION in
        self.saveQuestion = true
        print("OK")
    }))

    alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "غير موافق", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive, handler:{ ACTION in
        self.saveQuestion = false
        print("Not OK")
    }

    ))
    self.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And this is the function:

```
if (saveQuestion){
    ref.child("QuestionOfUsers").childByAutoId().setValue(label1.text)
    label1.text = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the user permission in user defaults so that it can be referred in all app launches.

```
func AlertOnce (Message: String){

    let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "أهلا بك", message: Message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "موافق", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { ACTION in
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "SaveQuestion")
        print("OK")

    }))

    alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "غير موافق", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive, handler:{ ACTION in
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "SaveQuestion")

        print("Not OK")
    }

    ))
    self.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

User Defaults can be read as follows

```
let saveQuestion = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "SaveQuestion")
if (saveQuestion){
    ref.child("QuestionOfUsers").childByAutoId().setValue(label1.text)
    label1.text = ""
}
```

Comment: No...you need not do anything while app terminate..that exception has nothing to do with this code

Answer (score 2):

If i understood correctly what you need is a persistent store, like a database, or userdefaults.

Example to save:

```
let value = true
UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "saveQuestion")
```

Example to get previously saved value:

```
let value = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "saveQuestion") as? Bool
```

Hope that finds your needs.

Comment: "UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()" isn't needed

Comment: Yeah i just realised it's deprecated. That's for the note.